# Union declaration with array pointer?

Tags: c

I have the following union structure:

```
typedef union Message
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned short header: 16;
    unsigned short header2: 16;
    unsigned int timestamp: 32;
    unsigned int payload: 32;

  } pieces;
  unsigned short whole[6];
}Message;
```

If I declare this way it works

```
Message msg = {.whole={255,255,255,0,255,0}};
```

I am just wondering there is any solution to declare union by an exsisting array? Like this:

```
unsigned short arr[] = {255,255,255,0,255,0};
Message msg = {.whole=arr};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Using the name of an array has it "decay" to a pointer to the first element in almost all contexts.

BTW, this has nothing to do with the fact that your array is hidden inside a `union`. Arrays can't be assigned to and the only way to initialize them is by using an initializer as you did.

You could just use `memcpy` to copy the contents, though.